# Odoo 10 QWeb incorect encoding

Tags: reporting, odoo, qweb

Suddenly I have a funny problem.
Generated pdf looks like this: https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/352032225597980673/482205966126022656/unknown.png?width=1193&height=456

everywhere encoding set to UTF-8.
Does anyone have an idea how to fix it?

Comment: Show us how you generate the pdf

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer.

Comment: I found out that this was a problem in wkhtmltopdf module.